# List network Docker

Tags: networking, docker

I was wondering if there is a docker command to list all the containers with their network? I know there is docker network inspect, but that's to inspect a network. I'm looking for a command that shows for all the containers to which network they are connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is within `docker network inspect` if you specify all of the networks as arguments, which can also be done programmatically.  The line looks like this:

```
docker network inspect $(docker network ls -q)
```

The output is valid JSON, which can be modified to put in any format you need.